# Accessing ADLS Gen2 using Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, cloud, databricks

I am new to Cloud(Azure), trying to connect to ADLS Gen2 using Azure Databricks but not able to access it.
Step tried -

1. got the access key from Azure portal, which was for specific Storage account
2. Tried to create Score as well, which was looking for Key Vault.

Is there any other way by which we can directly read the data from ADLS using python or any other python module which can help us to achieve this.

Comment: Have you followed official docs? 
https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-get-started.html

Comment: Yes, i did follow all the official docs on the same. 
Actyally i am looking for some other way which can be done using some API from local as we are trying to do some POC.